# WSO2 Enrich array

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) and I need transform this payload:

```
[
   {
     "id":"1",
     "budget":"a"
   },
   {
     "id":"2",
     "bidget:"b"
   }
]
```

in this one using enrich mediator (if it's possible):

```
[
   {
     "id":"1",
     "budget":"a",
     "result":"1-a"
   },
   {
     "id":"2",
     "bidget:"b",
     "result":"2-b"
   }
]
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can work with XML message and create a XSL transformation

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this sample:

Input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<employees>
    <root>
        <id>1</id>
        <budget>a</budget>
    </root>
    <root>
        <id>2</id>
        <budget>b</budget>
    </root>
    <root>
        <id>3</id>
        <budget>c</budget>
    </root>
</employees>
```

My xslt:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <employees>
            <xsl:for-each select="employees/root">
                <root>
                    <id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                    </id>
                    <budget>
                        <xsl:value-of select="budget"/>
                    </budget>
                    <result>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(id,'-',budget)"/>
                    </result>
                </root>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </employees>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<employees>
    <root>
        <id>1</id>
        <budget>a</budget>
        <result>1-a</result>
    </root>
    <root>
        <id>2</id>
        <budget>b</budget>
        <result>2-b</result>
    </root>
    <root>
        <id>3</id>
        <budget>c</budget>
        <result>3-c</result>
    </root>
</employees>
```

So you can use an xslt mediator in WSO2 ESB(https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/XSLT+Mediator ) and this configuration or similar and work with your definitions.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you don't know about the length of array you con't transform it with enrich or payloadFactory. I found same problem in WSO2 ESB document. this JS function transform an array of objects.

```
function transform(mc) {
payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
results = payload.results;
var response = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
    location_object = results[i];
    l = new Object();
    l.name = location_object.name;
    l.tags = location_object.types;
    l.id = "ID:" + (location_object.id);
    response[i] = l;
}
mc.setPayloadJSON(response);
}
```

See scipte mediator in [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-AccessingcontentfromJSONpayloads) for more information.